# Is it OK to use an Array Check instead of Switch Statement for dynamic page content?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple static website, but my lesser knowledge in back-end code had me question my abilities. Is there any kind of security risk or anything else I might be overseeing to use an array check instead of switch statement?

For example this is the code I've been using until recently

```
// Default page
$current_page = 'home';

if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET)) {
    $current_page = $_GET['page'];
}

switch ($current_page) {
    case 'home':
        $page = 'pages/home.php';
        break;
    case 'about':
        $page = 'pages/about.php';
        break;
    case 'contacts':
        $page = 'pages/contacts.php';
        break;
    default:
        $page = 'pages/404.php';
}
```

and this is the code I've replaced it with. It just makes more sense to me to have the code that would expand in the future (as more pages are added later on) separate from the actual check that never changes, on top of that I think it looks nicer.

```
$pages = array(
    'home'              => 'pages/home.php',
    'about'             => 'pages/about.php',
    'contacts'          => 'pages/contacts.php',
    '404'               => 'pages/404.php',
);

// Default page
$page = $pages['home'];

if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET)) {

    $current_page = $_GET['page'];

    if(array_key_exists($current_page, $pages)){
        $page = $pages[$current_page];
    } else {
        $page = $pages['404'];
    }

}
```

Comment: They both work perfectly well. The second one looks even more clear and is easier to add pages to.

Answer (score 0):

They are both safe, but the second is a bit easier to manage.

Another approach would be something like this:

```
$subFolder = 'pages';
$current_page = $subFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'home';

if (array_key_exists('page', $_GET)) {
    $current_page = $subFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_GET['page'] . '.php';
}

if (file_exists(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $current_page)) {
    $page = $current_page;
} else {
    $page = $subFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '404.php';
}

echo $page;
```

This does not require you to edit your code every time you add a new page. The code itself checks if the requested page exists in the pages directory.